# Ruby | DateTime

Tags: ruby, datetime

I was working with a ruby script to push stats into a time series kairos db and encountered the 'Datetime' class in ruby.

My question is does `DateTime.now` differ from `DateTime.now()`?

And if it does, can I get an example of their outputs?

Comment: _"can I get an example of their outputs"_ – you can open `irb` and type the two expressions yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between `DateTime.now` and `DateTime.now()`. Parentheses are optional in method calls in Ruby.

You can check some documentation about calling methods in Ruby [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html).

Example of both calls returning the exactly same result:

```
(local dev):0> DateTime.now
=> Thu, 14 May 2020 16:52:11 +0100

(local dev):0> DateTime.now()
=> Thu, 14 May 2020 16:52:15 +0100
```

Answer (score 1):

No differences. They are the same method call. In Ruby, you can call any method with or without parentheses. And there's no "public fields" in Ruby, only public methods, so the only thing you can "dot" is methods.